# Rotate image counterclockwise

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have circle which is rotating for the hour hand.

Here I tried to spin it counterclockwise:

```
<img src='http://aprilzero.com/static/images/rings_desktop/1.png'>

var $circle = $("img"), degree = 0, timer;
    var x = "-" + degree + 'deg';

function rotate(x) {  
      $circle.css({ WebkitTransform : 'rotate(x)',
                  '-webkit-transition-duration': '0.5s'
                  });
      timer = setTimeout(function() {
            ++degree; rotate();
      },100);

}
rotate();
```

How can I rotate my image counterclockwise?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/f7RNQ/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative angle:

```
var $circle = $("img"), degree = 0, timer;

    function rotate() {
      $circle.css({ WebkitTransform : 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
                  '-webkit-transition-duration': '0.5s'
                  });

      timer = setTimeout(function() {
            --degree; rotate();
        },100);

    }

rotate();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f7RNQ/18/